# Asking for facebook app permissions in parts

Tags: facebook, permissions

i have a facebook application..Since the roll out of the new auth the user has to go through 2 steps to  use the app.. First step is of basic info and the second step is of extended permissions.. I want to get the extended permission later during the app as this step turns off many users....

i want to first only use the basec auth 2.0 with only the basic info of user, NO extended permissions...and provide a link in the app and when the user click on publish button then the user should be directed to the extended permission page....

Answer (score 1):

You can define what permissions your app needs using the "scope" parameter. For your use-case, you can limit the initial login scope to the basic permissions. You can present the user with more permissions later in your app.

For example, the following login button will only ask for the 2 specified permissions -

```
<div class="fb-login-button" scope="email,user_checkins">Login with Facebook</div>
```

At a later stage in your app, you can present the following button -

```
<div class="fb-login-button" scope="email,user_checkins,user_status">More Permissions</div>
```

The user will be prompted to grant the additional `user_status` permission.